# .nextLine() versus .next()?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

and thank you for your time,

I've been coding for a month now, and a couple of times I have an issue regarding `nextLine`:

```
        gen = sc.nextLine();
        ge = gen.charAt(0);
```

In this case there is an issue because from what I read "The `nextLine()` method scans everything on the current line and then advances the pointer past that line. So when you call the `charAt()` method, you are calling it on the next line, which is blank space, and thus an error is occuring."

My question is, if `nextLine` may cause this kind of problem, what is the point of using it at all? I could simply put `.next()` for it to work.

Comment: gen.charAt(0) doesn't have anything to do with what NextLine does to advance -- it accesses the first (0th) char in gen, which is a representation of the line already read.

Answer (score 2):

As Jim said in the comment, `charAt(0)` is unrelated to `next()` vs. `nextLine()`.
`charAt(0)` is reading from the `String` *read from* the `Scanner`, not reading directly from the `Scanner` itself.

Ergo, where the pointer is makes no difference (to the best of my knowledge) to what is being read by `charAt(0)`. Hopefully that clears it up a bit.